# change database service name using a procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to create a procedure in order to change my Oracle database's service name.
I use execute immediate but I can not use full string because it have more than 255 characters.

I tried like follows, but I still have an error:

```
DECLARE
  db_domain varchar2(512);
  service_names varchar2(4000);
  service_names2 varchar2(4000):='';
  sqlstring varchar2(4000);
BEGIN

  select value into service_names from v$parameter
  where name='service_names';
  select value into db_domain from v$parameter
  where name='db_domain';

  service_names:= service_names || ', ' || 'abcdef.' || db_domain|| ','|| ' abcdefghij.'|| db_domain ||','||' abcdefghij.'|| db_domain ||',' ||' abcdefghij.'|| db_domain || ',';
  service_names2:='abcdefghij.'|| db_domain || ',' ||' abcdefghij.'|| db_domain;    
  execute immediate '''alter system set service_names = '''||service_names||''','''||service_names2||''' scope=memory;''';
END;
/

ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
ORA-06512: at line 17
```

How can I modify this? Thank you!

Comment: `execute immediate` allows even CLOB, i.e. your dynamic statement can be several TByte long.

Comment: The problem is not how long can be the statement, is that service_names parameter can have only 255 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issues are:

- The dynamic statement must not end with colon `;` - remove it
- Remove the quotes at beginning and end of dynamic statement

It must be like this

```
execute immediate 'alter system set service_names = '''||service_names||''','''||service_names2||''' scope=memory';
```

However, are you sure about the service names? This statement will set 2 service names for your DB

1. `abcdef_1.dbs.internal.domain.com, abcdef.dbs.internal.domain.com, abcdefghij.dbs.internal.domain.com, abcdefghij.dbs.internal.domain.com, abcdefghij.dbs.internal.domain.com,`
2. `abcdefghij.dbs.internal.domain.com, abcdefghij.dbs.internal.domain.com`

   Is this your intention? Having a service name **`abcdef_1.dbs.internal.domain.com, abcdef.dbs.internal.domain.com, abcdefghij.dbs.internal.domain.com, abcdefghij.dbs.internal.domain.com, abcdefghij.dbs.internal.domain.com,`** looks very suspicious.

Comment: It is just an example

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a DBA.

Before executing a command, it is (usually always) a good idea to display the command, using DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE.

If you do that, this is how ALTER SYSTEM looks like:

```
'alter system set service_names = 'kc11g, abcdef., abcdefghij., abcdefghij., abcdefghij.,','abcdefghij., abcdefghij.' scope=memory;'
                                                                                        ---
                                                                                        Here
```

I marked a spot which looks suspicious. What do you think?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE to view the output of the command and it looks like this: 
 'alter system set service_names = 'abcdef_1.dbs.internal.domain.com, abcdef.dbs.internal.domain.com, abcdefghij.dbs.internal.domain.com, abcdefghij.dbs.internal.domain.com, abcdefghij.dbs.internal.domain.com,','abcdefghij.dbs.internal.domain.com, abcdefghij.dbs.internal.domain.com' scope=memory;' 
If i execute this, it works.

Comment: Huh, if it works, I wouldn't know what else to suggest. As I said, I'm not a DBA, it's just thought that SERVICE_NAMES won't accept two strings. Sorry; someone else will have to assist.